# How to use append-map in Racket (Scheme)

Tags: scheme, racket, procedural-programming, procedures

I don't fully understand what the append-map command does in racket, nor do I understand how to use it and I'm having a pretty hard time finding some decently understandable documentation online for it.  Could someone possibly demonstrate what exactly the command does and how it works?

Answer (score 11):

The `append-map` procedure is useful for creating a single list out of a list of sublists *after* applying a procedure to each sublist. In other words, this code:

```
(append-map proc lst)
```

... Is semantically equivalent to this:

```
(apply append (map proc lst))
```

... Or this:

```
(append* (map proc lst))
```

The applying-append-to-a-list-of-sublists idiom is sometimes known as *flattening* a list of sublists. Let's look at some examples, this one is right [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._append-map%29%29) in the documentation:

```
(append-map vector->list '(#(1) #(2 3) #(4)))
'(1 2 3 4)
```

For a more interesting example, take a look at this [code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#Scheme) from Rosetta Code for finding all permutations of a list:

```
(define (insert l n e)
  (if (= 0 n)
      (cons e l)
      (cons (car l) 
            (insert (cdr l) (- n 1) e))))

(define (seq start end)
  (if (= start end)
      (list end)
      (cons start (seq (+ start 1) end))))

(define (permute l)
  (if (null? l)
      '(())
      (apply append (map (lambda (p)
                           (map (lambda (n)
                                  (insert p n (car l)))
                                (seq 0 (length p))))
                         (permute (cdr l))))))
```

The last procedure can be expressed more concisely by using `append-map`:

```
(define (permute l)
  (if (null? l)
      '(())
      (append-map (lambda (p)
                    (map (lambda (n)
                           (insert p n (car l)))
                         (seq 0 (length p))))
                  (permute (cdr l)))))
```

Either way, the result is as expected:

```
(permute '(1 2 3))
=> '((1 2 3) (2 1 3) (2 3 1) (1 3 2) (3 1 2) (3 2 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

In Common Lisp, the function is named "mapcan" and it is sometimes used to combine filtering with mapping:

```
* (mapcan (lambda (n) (if (oddp n) (list (* n n)) '()))
        '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
(1 9 25 49)
```

In Racket that would be:

```
> (append-map (lambda (n) (if (odd? n) (list (* n n)) '()))
            (range 8))
'(1 9 25 49)
```

But it's better to do it this way:

```
> (filter-map (lambda (n) (and (odd? n) (* n n))) (range 8))
'(1 9 25 49)
```