# map a function over a list of lists and concatenates the result into a list

Tags: scheme, mapping, concatenation, racket

How can I map a function for instance (square x) over a list of lists (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4)) and at the same time concatenates the result. For example the result would be (1 4 9 16).
I can't find any detailed explanations on the web... thanks for any advice!

Best Regards, Eunice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617095/how-to-use-append-map-in-racket-scheme#14617333

Comment: thank you for the link chunjef. I will go through it:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use append-map in Racket (Scheme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617095/how-to-use-append-map-in-racket-scheme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(append-map (lambda (slst) (map sqr slst))
            (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4)))
```

The innermost `map` squares each number, and the outermost `append-map` traverses the sublists, appending them at the end. In case your language doesn't support `append-map`, here's an equivalent solution:

```
(apply append
       (map (lambda (slst) (map sqr slst))
            (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4))))
```